# How to capture post data to use in another application in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to Capture the posted data form a Cognito Form to be able to use it in another part or plugin on my WordPress site?

What I need to do is create a form with several questions. There will be groups of conditional logic depending on the previous answer. when the form is submitted I need to capture that data to be able to use it for a different plugin and to send the user to a different page of my site.

Is this possible?

Comment: Wasn't sure what you meant by adding comments to your question so adding it here as well --- Thanks for the quick response -- I want to try using the 2nd option as JSON, can you elaborate a little on what I need to put in the URL field? I have a page ready where I want to receive the posted data, but not sure how you are sending it? I know php and jQuery/javascript so I can do this but I need a little more information in order to know how it is being sent oe what is your application expecting me to put in the URL field? Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms.

You have a couple of options:

1. You can pass information to another page via the redirect url and querystring paramaters:
   https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/181/building-forms/posting-data-through-the-redirect-url
2. You can post the entire form as JSON to a webhook:
   https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/66/data-integration/webhooks

Your best option in this case would likely be the first option as it will happen synchronously and would support data to both scripts on the client and code on the server.  Please add comments to your question to clarify it if this does not answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response -- I want to try using the 2nd option as JSON, can you elaborate a little on what I need to put in the URL field? I have a page ready where I want to receive the posted data, but not sure how you are sending it? I know php and jQuery/javascript so I can do this but I need a little more information in order to know how it is being sent oe what is your application expecting me to put in the URL field?  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: It sounds like the first option will work best for you, as the JSON option is more for integrating systems together, not handling the flow of a user from one page to the next.  Follow the documentation to pass the fields you want as query string parameters for your redirect URL.  We'll likely support posting the entire entry as JSON to the redirect page in a future release.

Comment: I should also add that in our next release (hopefully next week) you will have an enhanced editor for building the redirect URL that will make this easier as it will allow you to insert form fields from a pick list similar to the Content text editor.

Comment: aahhh I see, ok I will pass the fields using query strings, thanks for responding... But so glad to hear you may be supporting posting the entire entry as JSON soon :) Thanks!

Comment: @JamieThomas, what about the form submission being automatically entered into a spreadsheet, such as Google Docs (via Google Forms)?

Comment: The best way to get data into another cloud service without programming is to use our Zapier integration support: https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/integrations